# MVC Default Area Not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I have a web site that had no areas registered. Then I registered an area called "`MyNewArea`".

Now my default website links like blogs etc no longer work.

So I now have an areas folder with a single area in it and the default folders when I created the project in the first place.

In my area `AreaRegistration` class I have;

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "MyArea_default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

but this looks like it conflicts with the default one of

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

What do I need to do to get the area to work with the default site and controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the new area route table to be:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "MyArea_default",
    "MyNewArea/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "MyNewArea", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're right, that mapped route would conflict (in the sense of *"conflict"* as in it will be matched first).  You would need to alter your mapped Area route to be something like:

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "MyArea_default",
            "MyArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "MyAreaController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The reason why your URLs broke after you added this Area (and in turn the Area route), it used your Area route for handling that didn't exist in your `MyArea` Area.

Comment: I still need to specify the controller to use else the same issue occures.

Comment: @griegs Well technically you don't.  That is simply for parameter defaults.  So yes, if you don't explicity specify a controller you will have an issue.  But I have edited my answer to include the default of the `controller`.